# Google Map does not appear iOS sdk?

Tags: ios7, google-maps-sdk-ios

I Use Google Map iOS SDK in my app but I have this issue :

When I used google example for iOS like the following code it work fine but it will loaded in full screen mode because it take the main `view` in the `ViewController`.

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.868
                                                        longitude:151.2086
                                                             zoom:6];
GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];

marker.position = camera.target;
marker.snippet = @"Hello World";
marker.map = mapView;
self.view = mapView;
```

But I need it to be in subView , u know because toolbar or top bar whatever .

I add subView to `myViewController` and make an `IBOUtle` then I link the mapView to it like this :

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.868
                                                        longitude:151.2086
                                                             zoom:6];
GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];

marker.position = camera.target;
marker.snippet = @"Hello World";
marker.map = mapView;
mySubView = mapView;
```

but the View will be white/empty no map loaded/or add as subView, so I tried the following , change the subView type from `UIView` to `GMSMapView` and this make the map appear and loaded.

The strange problem that I can't do anything with this Map like the `GMSMarker` does not appear , or `GMSCameraPosition` does not show your the correct position/not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**if your outlet is a UIView** and you make the map in code, you have to add it.

Obj-C:

```
mapView.frame = mySubview.bounds;
[mySubview addSubview:mapView];
```

Swift:

```
mapView.frame = mySubview.bounds;
mySubview.addSubview(mapView)
```

**if your OUTLET is a mapview** then use that and dont make a new one

```
mapView = (GMSMapView*)mySubView;
```

Comment: thx :D a lot  I notice that I forget everything about "bounds" :D thx

Comment: and yeah "mySubView" it is just an  
alias name use it here :P